# WidgetKit @StateObject not updating View

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm having trouble understanding how to make my `SwiftUI` data model example work with my Widget. It's working in my test app just fine, I observe changes immediately. When I attempt the Widget, I can see the data being printed in console but no changes are happening in my `View` in `WidgetKit`. I'm using a `ObservableObject` class and `@Published` variables. I've attempted to use a `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject` and an `@EnvironmentObject` and the same results. Always results in No game today. My data model is `Combine` related, not sure if that has anything to do with why I can't see data changes in my `WidgetKit`'s `View`.

**SwiftUI App example working**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data = CombineData()
    @State private var showSortSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var nhlTeams: TeamOrder = .NewYorkIslanders
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if data.schedule?.dates.first != nil {
                    Text("Game today")
                } else {
                    Text("No game today")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.showSortSheet.toggle()
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.up.arrow.down")
                    }
                }
            })
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showSortSheet) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Teams:"), buttons: [TeamOrder.NewYorkIslanders, TeamOrder.MontrealCanadiens].map { method in
                    ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("\(method.rawValue)")) {
                        self.nhlTeams = method
                        data.fetchSchedule(self.nhlTeams.rawValue)
                        print("\(self.nhlTeams.rawValue)")
                    }
                })
            }
            .onAppear {
                data.fetchSchedule(self.nhlTeams.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Widget `@StateObject` (No data changes)**

```swift
struct ExampleEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var widgetFamily
    @StateObject var model = CombineData()
    @ObservedObject var model = CombineData()
    /*@EnvironmentObject private var model: CombineData*/
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if model.schedule?.dates.first != nil {
                Text("Game today")
            } else {
                Text("No game today")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            model.fetchSchedule(entry.configuration.teams.rawValue) {
                WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "NHL_Widget")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Widget 2 TimelineEntry (No data changes)**

```swift
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
    let model: CombineData
}

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        let currentDate = Date()
        let model = CombineData()
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration, model: model)
        entries.append(entry)
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        model.fetchSchedule(entry.configuration.teams.rawValue) {
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var widgetFamily
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if entry.model.schedule?.dates.first != nil {
                Text("Game today")
            } else {
                Text("No game today")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Widgets are static, the view you provide on `getTimeline` is what will be displayed as is and won't be updated, so the call to `fetchSchedule` on `onAppear` won't even be executed. Once you execute the completion handler in `getTimeline`, no more code is executed.

To display data on your widgets you need to fetch your data in `getTimeline`, create a view that displays the data from the start, and return that entry in your completion handler.

In your last example I would suggest that you create your entry in the completion handler of `model.fetchSchedule` and pass the `schedule` object to your view.

Comment: You were absolutely correct, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! It’s working now https://imgur.com/a/A5QzKaJ